# Batch Safe App Txs on behalf of users in frontend - how?

Tags: gnosis-safe, frontend

I am building a safe app integration on our dApps frontend. The dApp allows people to provide liquidity to a DEX by approving a router to spend two tokens and then invoking an `addLiquidity` transaction on the router to complete the deposit.

The desired functionality is that when the connected wallet is a safe, we batch these three operations together on behalf of the user so they can sign one batch and then execute `approve + approve + addLiquidity`

The entire desired flow works happily from a script (here: https://github.com/ArrakisFinance/safe-example-script/blob/main/script.ts)

Here's the most relevant part:

```
  const safeTransactionData: MetaTransactionData[] = [
    {
      to: TOKEN_0,
      data: payloadA0,
      value: "0",
    },
    {
      to: TOKEN_1,
      data: payloadA1,
      value: "0",
    },
    {
      to: ARRAKIS_V2_ROUTER,
      data: payload,
      value: "0",
    },
  ];

  const safeTransaction = await safeSdk.createTransaction({ safeTransactionData, onlyCalls: true });
```

the issue is this creates a delegatecall type transaction through the MultiSendCallOnly contract. As far as I can tell the delegatecall is necessary to make the transaction flow work (you can't do approval from safe through multicaller without using delegatecall). But frontend libraries are not allowed to craft Safe App transactions that use delegatecall as far as I understand for safety reasons. So how can we proceed to give the desired user experience to safe users using the existing sdks. (NOTE: currently we use wagmi and rainbowkit in the frontend, but I'm open to using other libraries if it makes the desired feature set possible)